# memory layout in multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Left
{
   char i = 'k';
};

struct Right
{
   int a = 99;
};

class Bottom : public Left, public Right
{};

int main()
{
    Bottom b;

    Left l = b;
    cout << l.i;

    Right r = b;
    cout << r.a;

    return 0;    
}
// output
// k99
```

How did this work?

if the memory layout of Bottom is:

```
Left
Right
Bottom
```

Then slicing `b` (i.e. `Bottom`) to `Left` object, should be ok, but how can it work when I slice `Bottom` to `Right` object?

Note: all this would be ok if I used casting. But I did not.

Comment: You sliced out the `Right` part, what is the problem?   In other words you called `Right::Right(Right const &)` with `b` as argument and that function can read `b.a` and assign `this->a`

Comment: When I do `Right r = b` I obtain a `Right` object from a `Bottom` object, without casting. so how did the compiler figure out the correct offset?

Comment: The compiler decides what the memory layout is going to be for `Bottom`, it knows where the parts are in just the same way it knows where any particular member variable is

Comment: *"all this would be ok if I used casting"* => What information would be available at compile time that a casting operator would use that a copy initialization could not also use as well?

Comment: @HostileFork Well nothing more, nothing less. I thought casting was a way for a human to tell the compiler to go and find correct offset. Otherwise, it I thought that `Right r = b` should end up invoking a conversion assignment `Right& operator=(const Bottom&)`

Comment: The memory layout has nothing to do with anything. Slicing is just copying of subobjects.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I updated question slightly to prove a point. I now use pointers, and it still works. In this case, I am not creating a new `Right` and `Left` objects I am just using a parent pointer to refer to the `Bottom` object

Comment: Your last edit completely changes the question - please roll back and post a new question if you have one

Comment: Ah I thought so, sorry that's what I meant, will do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Bottom` to `Right` or to `Left` is a proper conversion, not just a slicing.  The compiler generates code using the correct offset of the sub-object in `Bottom`.

This [Dr.Dobbs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/multiple-inheritance-considered-useful/184402074) should be of interest to you.

Comment: So why use static_cast<> ever then? If the compiler can figure out that I am not slicing but converting, what's the point of the cast

Comment: @Kam some conversions require a cast operator if they're deemed to be "dangerous"  (and/or for historical reasons) to reduce the risk of accidentally causing undefined behaviour. For example converting base to derived requires a cast, because the base might not actually be a base of the particular derived.  But derived-to-base does not require a cast because all deriveds have that base. It's nothing to do with information